# Serverless Framework: specify ephemeral storage size for AWS Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

AWS Lambda has recently add an option to specify more ephemeral storage (the filesystem mapped to the `/tmp` directory in the Lambda container), from the default of 512 MB up to a maximum of 10GB.

Link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/

In AWS console this setting is accessible through Console > Lambda > (function) > Configuration > Ephemeral storage (right next to the 'Memory' option which was there already).

But so far I have not figured out how to configure a non-default ephemeral storage size through `serverless.yml`. Memory is allocated through the key `memorySize` (either in the `provider` section or overridden per function).

Is there a similar way to configure more ephemeral storage?

Answer (score 10):

As per the documentation in this page https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml, you can specify this under the function

ephemeralStorageSize: value

Comment: Thanks! I must have read over it. I tried `ephemeralStorage` but it wasn't recognized. Just missed the `Side` suffix :)

Comment: Ensure also that you are using the latest version since older ones do not recognize this property, as pointed out here: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/11050 and here https://forum.serverless.com/t/ephemeralstoragesize-not-getting-updated-and-reverting-on-deploy/17636